# How to squeeze error message out of PDO?

Tags: php, error-handling, pdo

I can't seem to get any error message from PDO:

```
#$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
try {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare('@$%T$!!!');
  print_r($sth);
  print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

It is giving out only:

```
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => @$%T$!!!
)
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
)
```

setAttribute doesn't help anything.

It's PHP 5.3.3 Apache 2.0 Handler 
PDO Driver for MySQL enabled 
Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $

What can I do to get error information?

Comment: What does `print_r($sth->errorInfo())` prints out ?

Comment: @shamittomar I have tried it too, it giving out an array of 3 empty elements

Answer (score 66):

setAttribute *will* cause PDO to throw up errors or exceptions - the latest when you *execute* the query.

For emulated prepared statements, there is no check in `prepare()`:

> Emulated prepared statements does not communicate with the database server so PDO::prepare() does not check the statement.

But there will be one in `execute()` when the query gets sent to the server.

However, the mySQL driver supports native prepared statements since mySQL 4.1 anyway, so this shouldn't apply. Using

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

*must* cause an exception for the query you use.

Comment: man page example doesn't execute either: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php and with execute still no luck

Comment: @Col what if you set `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`?

Comment: @Col If you set `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and there are no exceptions neither from `prepare()` nor `exec()` then something else is wrong - in that case, I have no idea what

Comment: this one worked. Add it to the answer please, so I can accept it. though it still puzzling me, why errorInfo() doesn't work

Comment: @Col I added it. PDO is extremely secretive about database errors, but I would have expected `errorInfo()`  to work, too

Comment: Emulated prepare statements seems to be turned on by default for Mysql PDO.... for some reason. You have to explicitly turn emulation off.

Answer (score 5):

I too was trying to get the information from `errorInfo()` at the database handle level, but I ended up getting the information from the statement level with `PDOStatement::errorInfo()`

Per PHP web site:

> PDO::errorInfo() only retrieves error information for operations performed directly on the database handle. If you create a PDOStatement object through PDO::prepare() or PDO::query() and invoke an error on the statement handle, PDO::errorInfo() will not reflect the error from the statement handle. You must call PDOStatement::errorInfo() to return the error information for an operation performed on a particular statement handle.

Answer (score 4):

This will print error code as well its corresponding detailed message.

Advice: this is just a demonstration. Just use for debugging purpose. Don't enable to show error messages to the public in a release version.

```
try{
connection=$this->get_connection();//here i brought my connection string
connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
/**
Do your works here..
//$statement=$connection->prepare($sql);
//if you are using errorInfo use after prepare statement before execute.here in this method i am not using it.
//print_r($statement->errorInfo());
**/

$statement->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
              //this will echo error code with detail
              //example: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nasme' in 'field list'
              echo $e->getMessage();
            }
//$statement=null;
```

Comment: i don't understand why my answer was edited so badly n minus voted(-) as we know it was a demonstration of how to do something. its the only way to accomplish it while debugging the code. it shows detailed error message with error code.now i don't seem this answer is anything :/ why not delete it ..

Comment: Ah, you've restored the original code - fair enough. If it gets modified in a way that changes your intent again, please raise a moderator flag rather than engaging in an edit war - thanks. I'll fix the all-caps - we have a 'no shouting' rule here `:-)`

Comment: @YourCommonSense: please leave this answer alone. It already has a moderator report. If you have some feedback for the solution, feel free to expand upon the link you have provided in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first `execute` the query and then check for errors: So do it like this:

```
 $sth->execute();
```

and then check for errors. Then you will get errors, if any.

Comment: which is, after all, what the question is about. Why was this posted as answer, and not a comment? And why did it get so many upvotes?