# mysqli INSERT anomaly

Tags: php, insert, mysqli, row

I have the following table:

```
ID: bigint autoinc
NAME: varchar(255)
DESCRIPTION: text
ENTRYDATE: date
```

I am trying to insert a row into the table. It executes without error but nothing gets inserted in database.

```
try {
    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (NAME, DESCRIPTION, ENTRYDATE) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $name= 'something';
    $desc = 'something';
    $curdate = "CURDATE()";
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $desc, $curdate);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    //redirect to success page
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    print $e;
}
```

It runs fine and redirects to success page but nothing can be found inside the table. Why isn't it working?

Comment: As a side note, you can have the SQL server perform the `NOW()` function instead of taking an extra step in your php.

Comment: Sorry for the typo here. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about replacing `DESCTIPTION` with `DESCRIPTION` inside the `$query`?

**Edit**

Just out of curiosity, I created a table called `mytable` and copy-pasted your code into a PHP script.

Here everything worked fine and rows got inserted, except that the binded parameter `CURDATE()` did not execute properly and the `ENTRYDATE` cell was assigned `0000-00-00`.

Are you sure you are monitoring the same database and table your script is supposedly inserting to?

What happens when going with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Have you verified that the script actually completes the insertion?

The following appears to be working as expected:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (NAME, DESCRIPTION, ENTRYDATE) VALUES (?, ?, CURDATE())";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $name= 'something';
    $desc = 'something';
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $desc);
    $stmt->execute();

     if ($conn->affected_rows < 1) {
        throw new Exception('Nothing was inserted!');
     }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    //redirect to success page
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: yes I have a separate config.php file for that. Just recheked and its fine. error_reporting(E_ALL); doesn't show any error still.

Comment: Thanks! this code works now. I tried the CURDATE() inside as suggested and just bound other parameters. It works now. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure there is no error? There seems to be a typo in your column name for example.

Note that PDO is *extremely* secretive about errors by default.

See [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo) on how to fix this.

Comment: The typo is here in this post only. My real query is fine. Sorry for that. I just corrected it. I am using **mysqli** not **PDO**

Comment: @Deepak ah, I see. Sorry. The point still stands though: An invalid query will not throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

Try preparing this query instead:

```
"INSERT INTO mytable (NAME, DESCRIPTION, ENTRYDATE) VALUES(?,?,CUR_DATE())"
```

And check the results of `$stmt->execute()`. It would have given you a warning that `"CUR_DATE()"` (sic) is not a valid `DATE`.

You can check if a statement was correctly executed by checking the return value of `execute()` and querying the [`errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) method:

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
   throw new Exception($stmt->errorInfo(), stmt->errorCode());
}
```

Be aware that upon failure, `execute()` does not throw an exception automagically. You'll have to check for successful operation and failure for yourself.

Comment: Just tried it. There seems to be error. It doesn't redirect but no error is shown. Isn't that my catch exception should spit out errors? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I just check with this code and got 'object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { }'. What is this? Seems like CURDATE() have something to do with this. Any thought? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that autocommit is OFF?

If so then you have to commit your insert like so

```
/* commit transaction */
$conn->commit();
```

Regards

Comment: tried it but it still show successful but no entry in table. Any thoughts?