# PDO Database access WHERE title = $title

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to learn to use PDO instead of MySQLi for database access and I'm having trouble selecting data from the database. I want to use:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE title=$title ORDER BY date ASC');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    echo $row['title']; 
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/owencont/public_html/owenstest.com/ratemystudents/index.php
>   on line 6

If I take out the WHERE statement it works fine. How can I select a row based on if it's value matches a variable?

Thanks,

Owen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a SQL syntax error, because you forgot to quote `$title`. It ended up as bareword in the query (also not even interpolated as string), resulting in an error. And your PDO connection was not configured to report errors. Use ->quote() on arguments before the ->query():

```
$title = $DBH->quote($title);
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE title=$title ");
```

Or better yet, use parameterized SQL:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE title=? ");
$STH->execute(array($title));
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be working then?

 $title = 'the title';
 
 $title = $DBH->quote($title);
 $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE title=? ORDER BY date ASC");
 $STH->execute( array($title) );
 
 while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['title']; 
 }

Comment: @Owen: No, do only one of the two. Either ->quoting, or `?` bound parameters with ->prepare and ->execute.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your method seems to be the best and safest.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PDO::prepare](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDOStatement::execute](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). The safest way to add user content to a query is to prepare a basic statement and bind the parameter to it. Example (note the question mark in the SQL statement):

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE title=? ORDER BY date ASC');
$STH->execute( array( $title ) );

while( $row = $STH->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make PDO throw errors so you can see what exactly goes wrong. See [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)
2. You are probably missing quotes around `$title` but this scenario really calls for [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

remove the variable out of the sql statement because its a php variable

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE title=' . $title . 'ORDER BY date ASC');
```

Comment: It's SQL concatenation without escaping and without quoting -- it's asking for SQL injection.  PDO has prepared statements with placeholders, and those should be used whenever possible.  "Correct" answers should not contain security vulnerabilities and worst practices.

Comment: You've got a lot of downvoting to do then :P Let the community vote up better correct answers that teach those methods, and save downvotes for totally wrong answers. That's just my opinion.

Comment: hm that makes sense Charles, thanks lol, I learned something new

but thanks alot Kevin for supporting me :P!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes as a parameter of the query-method.

The reason you're getting this error is because the query-method fails and so the $STH object isn't created. You should implement some error handling.