# Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDO Database access WHERE title = $title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223304/pdo-database-access-where-title-title)

Here is a sample of $message's content :

> String(108) "\n      cc je t'ai envoy� une invitation  A plus :p\n    "

Here is the error message :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object
>   in  B:\wamp\www\messages.php on line 101

My request that doesn't work :

```
    $resultats = $connexion->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message LIKE '%$message%'");
    $resultats->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $occurences= $resultats->rowCount();
```

Why does this one work? (I changed $message by a) :

```
 $resultats = $connexion->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message LIKE '%a%'");
        $resultats->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $occurences= $resultats->rowCount();
```

Comment: You didn't escape it properly. Use parameterized queries, if you're using PDO to begin with. And you didn't check for `$resultats` getting set, nor for any error messages.

Comment: Shouldn't you be parametrizing your query? I imagine your message has a quotation mark in it somewhere.

Comment: @mario & Waleed Khan Yes.. Thank you very much, the problem was from quotation marks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using PDO with the same techniques that were used for `mysql_*` doesn't do you any good, you need to take advantage of its [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
$query = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message LIKE ?");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query->execute(array('%'.$message.'%'))) {
    // process
}
else {
    // only for debugging purposes, not a live app
    var_dump($connexion->errorInfo());
}
```

It performs *all* necessary escaping automatically and correctly for you on parameters, that you pass via the `execute()` method.

---

As for `I used addslashes`: That is **not safe**. Use prepared statements as demonstrated above.

Unless you are generating SQL  – actual SQL logic, not filling in blanks with user generated content – you should *never* have a need for PHP variables within SQL.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with your code :o That's strange.

I also tried this =>            `$query = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message LIKE :msg");
            $resultats = $query->execute(array('msg' => '%'.$message.'%'));
            $resultats->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`                    But i'm having the same issue... However it's working with addslashes and a simple "execute".

Comment: @Meds See my edit on how to get an error message.

Comment: @phanto0m A var_dump of $message = string(21) "\n      salluuuut\n    "
And I'm getting a Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in messages.php on line 103. So it's the same error, line 103 =>     $resultats->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);. I'm pretty sure that my request is correct.

Comment: @Meds refresh the page to ensure you are seeing the most recent version of my post.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question once I've finished.

Comment: That was a small mistake from you, and a big one from me, because I didn't notice that you had set the FetchMode on the result instead of the query. So, $resultats->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) = $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: @Meds Oh, right, sorry, I got confused there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using PDO Prepare. This is the 'almost' equivalent to mysql_real_escape_string(). This will probably eliminate most (if not all) of your errors due to special characters.

Comment: I used addslashes. But thank you I'll take a look at prepare.