# My $query->fetch() doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo

**Question edited following the comments. It still doesn't work.**

Hi there,

I'm trying to learn how PDO works, but my script:

```
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT nombre, 
                                    tecnica,
                                    tamanno,
                                    estado FROM obra WHERE anno = ?");
$query->execute(array('2009'));
while ($item = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $item['nombre'];
}
```

Prints nothing. If I do:

```
var_dump($query->fetch())
```

I get *bool(false)*. After reading lots of examples I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try not to use special chars in table/field names. and surround them with ` `

Comment: What's with all the empty catch blocks? You're not going to have a valid PDO object in `$database` if the connection fails

Comment: You need to tell PDO to actually raise exceptions when an error occurs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: Porfavor evita usar acentos o caracteres especiales en los nombres de las columnas tabla ;)

Comment: what is the output when you execute the same query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @emaillenin I don't have phpMyAdmin installed on my localhost, but in the MySQL console I get the data which I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> while ($item = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
>     $item['nombre'];
> }
> ```
>
> Prints nothing.

That's because *you're not actually doing anything with `$item['nombre']`*.  Try:

```
while ($item = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

You should get your expected output.

If not, try adding this *before* your connection is opened:

```
PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and make sure that you have `display_errors` set to true.