# PDO Not Inserting Into Database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

Hopefully someone will be able to help me because I've been banging my head against the wall all night trying to solve this little problem.

I want to insert data into a database using PDO (which I am admittedly not the most knowledgeable about). I am using a statement that I have used many times in the past, but for some reason this time it's not working.  The statement is as follows:

```
$userID = "Johnny5"; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_info(user_id) VALUES(:user-id)";
         if($stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql)) 
         {
            $stmt->bindParam(":user-id", $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            return TRUE;
         } else {
            return FALSE;
         }
```

But unfortunately this is always returning `TRUE` without ever entering anything into my database.  I have tried every combination changes to the statement that I could think of, but I am still at a loss.

I hope someone out there can point out a really simple error that I have made.

Also, placing single quote marks around the parameter `:user-id` in the `$sql` string is the only way that I can get anything to appear into the database, but that obviously doesn't enter in any actual data into the database.

**EDIT**
I have also changed the PDO parameter types from `PDO::PARAM_STR` to `PDO::PARAM_INT` but have still had no luck.

After further investigation, `execute()` is returning `FALSE`.

**Solution**
Thanks to everyone for their guidance.  @Nabeel was correct in saying not to use placeholders in PDO parameters.

Comment: PDOStatement->bindParam Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. PDOStatement->execute Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. You can find out which command fails by checking the return value.

Comment: Have you tried placing: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1); on top of your script?

Comment: @hakre I have determined that execute() where the failure seems to be

Comment: @teuneboon, yes, error reporting is set as you have suggested, but I am receiving no further warnings.

Comment: [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dashes in your SQL statements.

Make this:

```
:user-id
```

as this:

```
:userid
```

Comment: I was finally able to use the error reporting to lead me to that same conclusion.  If only you had been here sooner @Nabeel.  Oh well, better late than never :)

Comment: I wish I could've been here as soon as you posted your question.

Answer (score 0):

`$userId` is a string in this code, yet you say it's in int by defining `PDO::PARAM_INT`. Try replacing it with `PDO::PARAM_STRING` or try setting `$userId` to a number(1 for example)

Comment: Sorry, that's another thing I tried - Originally I had the parameter set to str, I'll edit above to reflect that.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

If something fails, then there most certainly was an error. First you need to find out which statement fails by checking their return values (always read about every command you use in the PHP Manual first).

If you've located which command failed, use [PDOStatement->errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) to find out more about the concrete error.

That information should help you to solve your issue.

**Update:** And if you want to deal with Exceptions (as Pekka suggested): [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: thank you for the guidance.  hopefully i will be able to solve the issue.  i'll post if it becomes resolved