# PDO returning false when fetching

Tags: php, pdo

I have this method:

```
protected function _getByColumn($columnName, $value)                                                                                                                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->__tableName                                                                                                                                                                                           
                WHERE :column = :value";                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        $stmt = $this->__db->prepare($sql);                                                                                                                                                                                                
        $stmt->execute(array(':value' => $value, ':column' => $columnName));                                                                                                                                                               
        $val=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        var_dump($val);   //getting boolean false


}
```

am i doing something wrong in the way i do the PDO call? i had output `$columnName` and `$value` and also echod `$sql`, manually replaed `:column` and `:value`, and everything worked. suggestions?

edit:

```
string 'SELECT * FROM myTable
               WHERE :column = ':value'' (length=61)

string 'blog_id' (length=9) 

string 'a3sasidsf' (length=8)
```

all values are as expected.

Comment: Check that `$this->__tableName` actually exists, otherwise you'll be doing `SELECT * FROM WHERE ...`. And check `$this->__db->errorInfo`, which'd contain the server-side error message.

Comment: [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: Technically, there is no error message, since there is no error.  It's returning false since there is no matching row.  But if you did `_getByColumn('foo', 'foo')` it would always return all rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a bound param as an identifier.  Right now, your code is saying `$columname = $value` as opposed to the desired `{value of $columname} = $value`.  You cannot bind identifiers.  The best solution if you want to take in a variable column name is to white-list the input against known column names and then quote it.  So:

```
if (in_array($columnName, $columns)) {
    $sql .= '`' . $columnName . '` = :value';
} else {
    die('illegal column');
}
```

Comment: i changed it so the column identifier is just a string that gets set before the prepare statement, however i'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: i lied. column name was the issue.