# PDO statment problem, query doesn't work when I use bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I can't figure this out. This is my variables:

```
$id = 1; 
$exp = 1;
$energy = 1;
$payout = rand ( 100 , 300 );
```

here is the query

```
    $sql =  'update players set ' .
            'exp = exp + :exp, ' .
            'energy = energy - :energy, ' .
            'cash = cash + :cash ' .
            'where id = :id';
```

An example of this as a string would be:

```
update players set exp = exp + 1, energy = energy - 1, cash = cash + 170 where id = '1'
```

When I input this in `phpmyadmin` it works. Thats why I don't understand why this does not work:

```
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':exp', $exp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':energy', $energy, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cash', $payout, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die ($e->getMessage() );
    }

    if ( !$result )
    {
        trigger_error("mysql: " . $sql, E_USER_ERROR);
        $data = array( "message" => T_gettext("Something went wrong."));
        return json_encode( $data );
    }
```

This results in a false `$result` = something wrong with query.

What have I done wrong? + how do I get a more detailed mysql error message from PDO?

Comment: Re the error message, try [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: Furthermore, you shouldn't catch Exception, but PDOException class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually throwing exceptions from your connection for you to catch? Try this and see if you get any error messages:

```
$db = new PDO($connection_string);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```