# Write PHP PDO queries as `dbName`.`tableName` as opposed to `tableName` - why?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm writing  a user registration function in PHP PDO, and I have found that my query will only run fine if it is written like this:

```
<?php
    $dbHost="localhost";
    $dbName="project";
    $dbUser="admin";
    $dbPassword="abcd";
    $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbName=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $query=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO project.users (userName, userEmail) VALUES (?,?)");
.....
```

On the other hand, it will not run if I write:

```
...
$query=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (userName, userEmail) VALUES (?,?)");
...
```

In that case, I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in C:\wamp\www\Tests\Test03\Index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\Tests\Test03\Index.php(11): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\Tests\Test03\Index.php on line 11

Why is it that I need to precise `project.users`?  Why isn't it enough to enter the table name, given that the db name itself is already in the PDO object?

Thank you!

JDelage

**UPDATE**  Please see accepted answer below.  Replacing `dbName=$dbName` with `dbname=$dbName` solves this problem.

Comment: because you have a typo in `dbame`? (**Edit:** Ah, that's not it - just saw your previous question.)

Comment: However, you didn't follow my advice and turn PDO's error output on as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505) using `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`. That should be your first step.

Comment: Fair point, I have edited the question to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Is this a direct copy and paste, or has it been edited?  I have a strong suspicion that `dbName` is written as `dBName` or other small case difference, resulting in the connection string being `mysql:host=localhost;dbName=`.  Can you echo out your DSN just to be certain?

Comment: That's a direct copy-paste.  However, I am interested in doing anything I can to clarify things.  What do you mean by "Can you echo out your DSN"?  I'm a beginner and any specifics would be most helpful.  Cheers.

Comment: I had the same problem just by leaving a space before or after the value for the "dbname".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently PDO was unable to set active database to be "project" and therefore you need to specify it every time.

Try to modify your line to look like this:

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
```

The only difference is that `dbname` is spelled all lower-case instead of yours `dbName`.

Alternatively, execute this SQL command after successfully establishing a connection:
`USE project;`, e.g.

```
$dbh->exec('USE project;');
```

Comment: Spelling `dbname` instead of `dbName` solves it.  Unbelievable - I was certain I had tried that...

Comment: I had the same problem just by leaving a space before or after the value for the "dbname".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"mysql:dbName=$dbName;host=$dbHost"
"mysql:dbName=$dbName;host=$dbHost;"
```

instead of:

```
"mysql:host=$dbHost;dbName=$dbName"
```

sometimes the order is important.