# Why PDO Exception Error Not Caught?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling

I have a PHP script with two deliberate typo mistakes in the statement for an SQL query:

```
try
{
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE non-existent_column=?");
 $stmt->blindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
catch(PDOException $err)
{
 var_dump($err->getMessage());
 var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

However, the script does not catch the error even after setting attribute to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

This is the full script. The second typo `blindValue` has been reverted back. The error remains uncaught:

```
<?php

$user= "user";
$password = "password";
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=Catalogue;host=localhost";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$id = 1000;

try
{
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE non-existent_column=?");
 $stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
catch(PDOException $err)
{
 echo "caught";
 var_dump($err->getMessage());
 var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
 exit();
}

var_dump($stmt);
var_dump($row);
echo "uncaught";
exit();

?>
```

Comment: If the exception ends up with the default error handler, can you show the message? Also you do have a typo in `->blindValue`. That would lead to a fatal error, not an exception.

Comment: @mario, you mean the default as in `$err` added above? I added that one too, no error message. The script skips through the entire catch block.

Comment: @mario, yes, that is the second typo. First one is the non-existent column.

Comment: If you do get the error message `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDOStatement::blindValue()` then that can't be caught with a `try/catch` declaration. That's not an exception, is an interpreter error.

Comment: @mario, I see.. but even if I correct this second error, the first error also couldn't be caught.

Comment: You still need to tell what exactly that message says. The full message, no excerpts.

Comment: @mario, I got no message from both `getMessage` and `errorInfo`. And no fatal error also.

Comment: So what you are actually saying is that the query seemingly succeeds, and thus you get no message/exception. What does `var_dump($stmt)` and `$row` say? Can you also test with just `->query("SELECT garbage FROM wrong");` in place of the `prepare/execute`?

Comment: Please give us a _complete_, self-contained example, see http://sscce.org/

Comment: I am not sure whether the query succeeds or not. This is what I get for `$stmt=object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(101) "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE non-existent_column=?" }` and for `$row=bool(false)`.

Comment: @mario, I tried `->query("SELECT garbage FROM wrong");`. It didn't reach pass the catch block. I am not sure whether it entered catch block since no error message is generated and echo string doesn't produce anything too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel, I read your post. Pekka says PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION must work, but it didn't in my case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your call to setAttribute() lacks the first parameter:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

If you didn't get a

```
Warning: PDO::setAttribute() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
```

your [error_reporting level](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is too low for a development server and/or you didn't keep an eye on [the error log](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) or didn't set [display_errors=On](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) (which ever you prefer; I prefer the error log over display_errors).

---

edit: please try

```
<?php
echo 'php version: ', phpversion(), "\n";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');  
    echo 'client version: ', $dbh->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), "\n";
    echo 'server version: ', $dbh->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION), "\n";
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch(PDOException $err) {
    var_dump($err->getMessage());
    die('...');
}

$id = 'foo';

try
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE `non-existent_column`=?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
catch(PDOException $err)
{
    var_dump($err->getMessage());
    var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
    die('....');
}

echo 'done.';
```

printed on my machine

```
php version: 5.3.5
client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $
server version: 5.5.8
string(94) "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'non-existent_column' in 'where clause'"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "42S22"
  [1]=>
  int(1054)
  [2]=>
  string(54) "Unknown column 'non-existent_column' in 'where clause'"
}
....
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine also. This is the right answer, because the only reason why an exception wouldn't be caught (when forced) is if PDO isn't in exception mode. This properly sets it in exception mode and works fine on my copy. +1 for a proper and detailed answer.

Comment: It works fine for me too. But I couldn't find where I had gone wrong with my script. Anyway, thanks. I will look into it further.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt->blindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This should be `$stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

You cannot catch *Fatal Errors* such as calling an undefined function/method.

Comment: @ ThiefMaster, I have reverted blindValue back to bindValue. The error remains uncaught :(

Answer (score -2):

I experienced this and realized it was my PHP configuration file.

xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1

Exceptions will always appear if this is true.