# False statement in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to run this simple query:

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname:mydb";
    $PDO = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
    $statement = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    var_dump($statement);  
} catch (PDOException $e) { exit($e->getMessage()); }
```

and this output:

```
bool(false)
```

I'm really getting mad about this error. I tried to run the query on my database. `$PDO` is a PDO Object so technically it is connected to the database. It also seem that nothing gets wrong in all the pro functions. Running the copied and pasted query from `$PDO->query()` on phpmyadmin return a list of 2 record. I don't know what to do seriously. I'm starting to pull my hair and hit the wall with the head (it's not a metaphor).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: @Pekka, sorry but how is it related?

Comment: Well, getting an error message would help you find out what the problem is, no?

Comment: Have you var_dump()'d `$PDO` as well? What does `$PDO->errorInfo()` show?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, "$PDO is a PDO Object".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a DSN problem.

```
dbname:mydb
```

should be

```
dbname=mydb
```

Don't you just love programming?

---

In addition to the above statement, you should nevertheless enable Exceptions in your PDO attributes. It's done by adding the following statement right after the connection:

```
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

#### Further Points

- ***Naming Convention*** - It's an accepted naming convention that **variable names** begin with a **lower case letter**, and every consecutive word is in **Camel Case**, or using **underscores**.
  Examples: `$pdo`, `$databaseConnection` `$awesomeMultipleWordedVariable`, `$another_awesome_multiple_worded_variable`.

Comment: OMG, thanks very much. You saved my life. I was going to kill myself.

Comment: +1 for a good catch! However, the OP should enable exceptions anyway ;).

Comment: Well spotted. But it's worth noting that `$PDO->errorInfo()` says `No database selected`. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: @middus: Added, plus I've added the naming convention point for further reference.

Comment: Regarding the naming conventions: in the php world many people use `$hello_i_am_a_var`.

Comment: Noted, however the point is to get rid of the `$PDO` Added nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable PDO Exceptions:

```
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```