# PDO UPDATE query does not update table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The code in question is like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['id'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }
    if (empty($title) or empty($content) or empty($id)) {
        $error = 'All fields are required!';
    } else {

        try {

            $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET article_title = ?, article_content = ? WHERE article_id = ? ");


            $query->bindValue(1, 'title');
            $query->bindValue(2, 'content');
            $query->bindValue(3, 'id');

            $query->execute();

            header('Location: index.php');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print_r($e->errorInfo);
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me no error whatsoever and the table does not update.

P.S. I am quite new to PHP in general so please bear with me if my errors are somewhat trivial, I just don't have anyone else to ask.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209677/mysql-update-using-pdo-and-prepared-statement-not-working

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: What tutorial you are trying to follow to?

Comment: It was a CMS tutorial youtube by phpacademy, i tried to change quite a lot of parts, and encountered some errors along the way.

Comment: 1. Thanks for adding your solution. However I've rolled it back, since was identical to the accepted answer aside from some minor variable changes. In future if you have a solution that is quite different to any of the answers given, I suggest adding it as an answer, to make it easier for future readers of your question. 2. If you're following a tutorial, it's worth hyperlinking it, in case anyone wishes to see where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: i don't see how the question is "too localized". this is the closest thing i've been able to find about what i need to do with SQL

Comment: Is it a possible duplicate, as indicated in the 1st comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to PHP then I would suggest you try an alternative way of executing queries with placeholders (?) since it is much simpler.

First set up your connection.

```
try {
  # First let us connect to our database 
  $db = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xx;charset=utf8", "xx", "xx", []); 
 } catch(\PDOException $e){
   echo "Error connecting to mysql: ". $e->getMessage();
 }
 $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Now call prepare/execute methods like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
        UPDATE articles 
        SET article_title = ?, article_content = ? 
        WHERE article_id = ?
 ");

 $stmt->execute(array($article_title, $article_content,$article_id));

 if($stmt->rowCount()) {
   echo 'success';
 } else {
   echo 'update failed';
 }
```

Comment: This gives me these errors: Notice: Use of undefined constant article_title - assumed 'article_title' on all the variables

Comment: @Robert Very sorry, I forgot `$` before the variables, I have updated the answer now

Answer (score 2):

```
$query->bindValue(1, 'title'); 
$query->bindValue(2, 'content'); 
$query->bindValue(3, 'id');
```

The second value to bindValue should be the *value*, not the name of the value, something like;

```
$query->bindValue(1, $title); 
$query->bindValue(2, $content); 
$query->bindValue(3, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```