# PDO Database Class, returning errors

Tags: php, error-handling, pdo

I have a PDO Database Class, I'm a little new to PDO so I don't know how I would go about returning errors so I can debug if something goes wrong. I just want to know the best methods of going about catching errors and returning them back to the request. Here is my database class:

```
class database {

private $dbh;
private $stmt;

public function __construct($user, $pass, $dbname) {
    $this->dbh = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname",
        $user,
        $pass,
        array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true )
    );

}

public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    return $this;
}

 public function bind($pos, $value, $type = null) {

 if( is_null($type) ) {
        switch( true ) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }

    $this->stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
    return $this;
}

public function execute() {
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll();
}

public function single() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: go through the link posted by pekka, he have the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch error in your "client code". Use try/catch blocks in every call that involves "execute" or "query" methods. Then you can head your application as you want whenever an error happens.

Comment: Thanks, both you and Pekka helped out.