# PDO validating login data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Okay.. I am completely new to this PDO stuff.. I have tried to recreate my mysql script (working) to a PDO script (not working).. I have tested that my DB login informations is correctly programmed for PDO..

This is my PDO script...

```
<?

session_start();
//connect to DB
require_once("connect.php");

//get the posted values
$email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
$pass=md5($_POST['psw']); 

//now validating the email and password
$sql - $conn_business->prepare( "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'");
$sql -> execute();
$count = $sql->rowCount();
$result = $sql -> fetch();
// Now use $result['rowname'];

$stmt = $conn_business->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'");
$stmt ->execute();
$act = $stmt -> fetch();

//if email exists
if($count > 0)
{
//compare the password
if(strcmp($result["password"],$pass)==0)
{
    // check if activated
    if($act["activated"] == "0")
    {
        echo "act"; //account is not activated yet
    }
    else
    {
        echo "yes"; //Logging in
        //now set the session from here if needed 
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    }
}
else
        echo "no"; //Passwords don't match
}
else
    echo "no"; //Invalid Login

?>
```

And this is my old mysql script...

```
session_start();
require_once("connect.php");
//get the posted values
$email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
$pass=md5($_POST['psw']); 

//now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT email, password members WHERE email='".$email."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 

$sql2="SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$act = $row2['activated'];

//if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    //compare the password
    if(strcmp($row['password'],$pass)==0)
    {
        // check if activated
        if($act == "0")
        {
            echo "act";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "yes";
            //now set the session from here if needed 
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        }
    }
    else
            echo "no";
}
else
        echo "no"; //Invalid Login
```

Does anybody know, what I have done wrong? It is an automatically script.. It is called through AJAX and return data based on 'no', 'yes' and 'act' that tells the AJAX/jQuery script what to do.. As I said - the mysql script is working, so please if anyone could tell me what I have done wrong with the PDO script..

EDIT:

when it returns the data to the jQuery script, this should happen:
if yes: start session, redirect to page2.php with session started.
else if act: write in a field that the account is not activated.
else: write that email and password didn't match.

The thing is, that when I try to write the correct e-mail and password - it continues to write : "email and password didn't match" instead of redirecting.. When I say that it is not working it is because the mysql script does as described but the PDO script doesn't..

And I have tried to change the 'echo "no";' to 'echo "yes";' to see if the login would start anyway, but somehow it continues to write that the email and password didn't match..

SOLUTION:

I ahven't told this because I thought it was unnecessary, but the reason for it not to work was because of that i have had my old mysql code in comment marks on top of the page, so that the session_start command didn't work.. After deleting the old code it worked, but then I found something else to change, and that is in the PDO script when it is validating it says:
    $sql - $conn_business->prepare( "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'");
and then I just changed the '-' after $sql to '=' and now, everything works perfectly... Anyhow thank you everybody.. hope this code can help others..

Comment: "not working" is pretty broad...are seeing any error messages or other debugging indicators?

Comment: One thing that catches the eye is that you're not doing any error chekcing after your queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo on how to do that.

Comment: @Pekka I've read it now, but I still don't know exactly how, where and why to do it.. :/ It is so easy with normal mysql, I just thought it wouldn't be that more advanced for dealing with PDO...

Comment: this line looks wrong: $sql - $conn_business->prepare( "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'");
what's that minus sign there, surely a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even read the manual before you "started using" PDO?

- That is not how prepared statements are supposed to be used! Your code is filled with SQL injections.
- Why are you selecting same row twice ?
- The [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) is **not** for checing if one string is identical to another.
- And hashing passwords as simple MD5 is just a sick joke.

  ```
  session_start();

  //very stupid way to acquire connection
  require_once("connect.php");

  //get the posted values
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
  if (filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
      // posted value is not an email
  }

  // MD5 is not even remotely secure
  $pass = md5($_POST['psw']); 

  $sql = 'SELECT email, password, activated FROM members WHERE email = :email';

  $statement = $conn_business->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $output = 'login error';

  if ($statement->execute() && $row = $statement->fetch())
  {
      if ( $row['password'] === $pass )
      {
          // use account confirmed
          if ( $row['activated'] !== 0 ) {
              $output = 'not activated';
              $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
          }

          $output = 'logged in';
      }
  }

  echo $output;
  ```

Comment: I understand the code you've wrote, and thank you very much for showing a perfect way of doing this.. But how would be the best way of connecting to a database? and if I have to match the posted password with the one in the Database, I have to md5 encode it to compare.

Comment: instead of "naked" MD5, you should be using [crypy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), with either Sha512 or Blowfish. As for connecting to the database, it encompasses much larger issues: the user authentication should be done by service (an object), which has the connection object provided to it in the constructor. I would consider application, in which modularity is achieved by including a lot of files with variables in global scope, a very flawed one.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the second query in your scripts is not necessary you could simple do

```
   SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=:EMAIL AND password=:PWS;
```

use **bindParam** method

```
   $qCredentials->bindParam(":EMAIL",$EMAIL);
   $qCredentials->bindParam(":PWS",$PWS);
```

then do more **understable** outputs rather than *yes* or *no*.. 
try *"Unable to login: Invalid credentials supplied"* for invalid types of values or
 *"Unable to login: Invalid credentials, couldn't find user"* for invalid user credentials.
You could try to start the session after the user has been successfully logged in your IF condition returning **yes**, and the methods

```
$PDOstatement->debugDumpParams()
$PDOstatement->errorInfo()
$PDOstatement->errorCode()
```

will help you understand what went wrong with a query!