# Detecting error/invalid/illegal queries using PDO driver (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: mysql, pdo

I just changed all my code from the old mysql driver to PDO.

So far I find that a lot of basic functionalities doesn't exist! Ex. no equivalency to `mysql_num_row` .. and so on (but that's not the point of this post :/ )

Usually with mysql driver, I'd do:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result){
    displayError(mysql_error());
}
```

How do you do similar thing using PDO?

Comment: Tell PDO to [throw exceptions in problematic situations](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: @Dcoder I tried } catch (PDOException $e) { but it didn't catch the error .. Although, if I get the error code it'd be 0000 which i believe means "illegal".

Comment: If it didn't catch the exception, you forgot to set `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. See ManseUK's answer.

Comment: @stackplasm did any of the answers below help you ? you should aim to accept an answer for every question you ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) there are 3 modes :

- `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` (default)
- `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`
- `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

I suggest you enable the last, which causes an exception to be thrown on error :

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$options);  // Example connection
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

then surround your statement in a `try/catch` block

```
try {
    // your query here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

Separate note - `mysql_num_row` in PDO :

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE x = y"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try { } catch {}`

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

### [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)