# Update data using PDO why it does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
<?php
$sTable = "mytable";    

$colUpdate = $_GET['field'];// database field name
$valUpdate = $_GET['val']; // the long string ,can be non-English   
$rowID = $_GET['id']; //number

    $pdo = PDO2::getInstance();
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8'); // for utf-8

    $sql = "UPDATE $sTable
            SET $colUpdate =:valUpdate
            WHERE id =:rowID ";      
    $req = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(":valUpdate",  $valUpdate);
    $req->bindValue(":rowID",  $rowID);

    $req->execute();
    $req->closeCursor();        
   ?>
```

What did I wrong here?Because it works if I did like this:

```
 <?php
    $sTable = "mytable";
    $pdo = PDO2::getInstance();
    $colUpdate = $_GET['field'];
    $valUpdate = $_GET['val'];      
    $rowID = $_GET['id'];

    $sQuery = " UPDATE $sTable SET  $colUpdate = '$valUpdate' WHERE  id = $rowID";
    $req = $pdo->prepare($sQuery);
    $req->execute();
    $req->closeCursor();    
?>
```

Comment: What you did wrong: you posted a question without describing the problem and you did not include any errors you're getting.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking for your query in your code. It is hence no wonder the code breaks when your query fails. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo on how to get an error message out of PDO

Comment: make sure that `colUpdate` is not empty; also it seems that one of your columns is meant to be called `order` wich is both misspelled in your code, and reserved word in `MySQL`. If that is the case, you should use backticks around the table name

Comment: why are you using `bindvalue` when you can simply use those variables in the statement itself.

Comment: @T-ShirtDude using the bindParam() method the string will be escaped etc. @ user777297 Did you create a good instance of PDO? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @stUrb you see my second option I used ,it works fines.thanks

Comment: Between the last `bindValue` and `execute()` lines in the first codebox, put in this: `$err = $req->errorInfo(); echo $err[2];` and tell us what it says.

Comment: Did you try to specify the kind of parameter you bind with: `PDO::PARAM_STR` or `PDO::PARAM_INT` ?

Comment: okay ,now it WORKS,thanks all of you.the problem is that I have to put REQUEST:  "&val="+encodeURIComponent(sValue)).so it will work all kind of string .

Comment: By the way, the fact that you are inserting `$colUpdate` directly into the query completely defeats the purpose of using prepared statements. It is derived straight from `$_GET` without any filtration or validation, and thus you are a wide open call for SQL injection attack. The best thing to do for this would be to pass `$_GET['field']` through a `switch()` statement with the `cases` being the names of your tables. This would essentially force `$colUpdate` to be either of the `cases` in the switch and nothing else. Please do this for the sake of your security!

Comment: @ZaneBien: It's only an example to show that without binding the values to placeholders, his query works...

Comment: @Truth no, it is also in his first codebox which I'm assuming is ***not*** an "example"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are using a Singleton
2. You aren't checking for errors
3. You're passing GET variables directly.

Let's address each, shall we?

### 1. You are using a Singleton

**[Singletons are evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what)**, they are set in the global space, which makes your application unstable, unreliable and untestable. Besides, what would you do if you needed **another database connection**?

#### Solution

Use a new PDO instance.

### 2. You aren't checking for errors

There aren't any error checking in your code, so if an error does come up, it is silently ignored.

#### Solution

Set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` in the constructor of PDO or using `setAttribute`. It also helps setting `PDO::EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false`.

### 3. You're passing GET variables directly into your query

You're passing `$colUpdate` directly inside your query, even if you are preparing the statement, variables passed directly into the query strings are not escaped.

#### Solution

Pass it in a placeholder, and bind the value. Also, your structure is most likely flawed if you need user input to determine the **column** you're updating.

After all of those, I come to the following code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Variable Initialization
 */
/** @var $table_name string Name of the table to insert */
$table_name = "mytable";

/**
 * @var $field_to_update string Name of field to update
 * @deprecated Should not be used! Database restructuring needed!
 */
$field_to_update = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['field']); //At least escape it!

/** @var $value_to_insert string */
$value_to_insert = $_GET['val'];

/** @var $row_id integer */
$row_id = $_GET['id'];

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name", "user", "password");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8'); // for utf-8

$sql = <<<MySQL
UPDATE $table_name
    SET $field_to_update = :valUpdate
    WHERE id = :rowID
MySQL;

$req = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$req->bindValue(":valUpdate", $value_to_insert, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue(":rowID", $row_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$req->execute();
```