# Why doesn't my query execute?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a query that get's fed these variables (but from a POST form):

```
$username = "John";
$email = "johnsmith@mail.com";
$passwordEnc = "9d4e1e23bd5b727046a9e3b4b7db57bd8d6ee684";
$activated = 0;
$activationKey = "5753a498f025464d72e088a9d5d6e872592d5f91";
```

The query is as follows:

```
$stmt = $dbu->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, activated, key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($username, $email, $passwordEnc, $activated, $activationKey));
```

There is no error, but the entry isn't added to my table named 'users'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: What does $stmt->execute return?

Comment: Please stick your prepare and execute inside a `try { } catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e; }` block, and tell us the results.

Comment: @Daedalus It shows no error when I do that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `password` and `key` with backticks

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, `password`, activated, `key`) VALUES ...
```

Comment: Thanks that saved me a lot of time! Forgetting that often.. Will accept when I can, have a good day!

Comment: I use the MySQL workbench for designing my queries. It highlights reserved words and you can see the problem from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html, just to save you some time 'Key' is the only word reserved on there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbu->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbu->errorInfo();
```

add this lines to get any pdo query error