# Issue with inserting value into a database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

what is the issue with this code , I'm using a form to insert some values into a database , i have a controller setup like that. when i submit the form , the value was not posted in the database, but if i remove all others fields and left only 2 fields in the form and post it ,it works so there's something that i miss,been trying to resolve for more than 6 hours .please some help :

```
//database insertion

 if (isset($_POST['VideoTITLE']))
 if (isset($_POST['ByArtist']))
 if (isset($_POST['GroupName']))
 if (isset($_POST['URL'])) 
 if (isset($_POST['VideoDate']))
 {

  try
 {
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO videoclip SET
        VideoTITLE = :VideoTITLE,
        ByArtist   = :ByArtist,
        GroupName  = :GroupName,
        URL        = :URL,
        VideoDate  = CURDATE()
        ';

    $s = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
    $s -> bindValue(':VideoTITLE',$_POST['VideoTITLE']);
    $s -> bindValue(':ByArtist',$_POST['ByArtist']);
    $s -> bindValue(':GroupName',$_POST['GroupName']);
    $s -> bindValue(':URL',$_POST['URL']);
    $s -> execute();
}
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    $error = 'error adding submitted data' . $e-> getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
  }
    header('Location:.');
    exit();
}
```

here's my html form setup:

```
<form action="?" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
   <legend>Song Info</legend>


<fieldset>
<label>Song Title </label>
<input type="text" id="VideoTITLE" name="VideoTITLE" placeholder="song name…">

<label>Artist </label>
<input type="text" id="ByArtist" name="ByArtist" placeholder="artist name…">

<label>Musical Group</label>
<input type="text" id="GroupName" name="GroupName" placeholder="Type something…">

<label>Poster link</label>
<input type="text" id="URL" name="URL" placeholder="Type something…">

</fieldset><br>
<input  type="submit" class="btn  btn-success" value="Post video">

</form>
```

Comment: What database, and what is the schema for the table?

Comment: Any reason that you're doing 5 `if` statements instead of doing `if(isset($_POST['VideoTITLE']) && isset($_POST['ByArtist']))` etc.?

Comment: If you `print_r($_POST)` are all the values you are checking `isset()` on set?

Comment: Related: [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: I have tagged MySQL arbitrarily as it is the usual case with PHP. You need to retag, if you're using other database system.

Comment: i'm learnin from book for beginner , the book only have 1 if , because it's only one field they want to add value , in project i  have 5 fields , so when i was try to resolve the issue , i was thinking may be i need to put 5 if instead of 1 ,if i need to replace it let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a couple of problems, maybe more:

1. You have `isset($_POST['VideoDate'])` in your if condition which will always be false since `VideoDate` is not in your form. You should take this out since you seem to want to set it using `CURDATE()` in your insert script.
2. your insert statement is incorrect. mysql inserts typically look like `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COL1, COL2) values('VALUE1', 'VALUE2');` so you should change your insert code to look like

   `$sql = 'INSERT INTO videoclip (VideoTITLE, ByArtist, GroupName, URL, VideoDate) values (:VideoTITLE, :ByArtist, :GroupName, :URL, CURDATE())';`

Comment: Who the hell is downvoting the correct answers in this question? +1 to even out

Comment: i fix it with your recommendations , i appreciate it: but after finishing posting but i receive this warning :Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at), but the value posted, but the redirect seems have an issue , what is the best way to correct it.

Comment: check that there is no space above your `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect for `INSERT`. It should be something like:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO videoclip (VideoTITLE, ByArtist, GroupName, URL, VideoDate) 
    VALUES (:VideoTITLE, :ByArtist, :GroupName, :URL, CURDATE())';
```

In addition, `$_POST['VideoDate']` is not valid as you do not have it in your form.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted? Seeing as it's correct and all

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the `if` statements wrong.

```
if (isset($_POST['VideoTITLE']) && isset($_POST['ByArtist']) && isset($_POST['GroupName'])
    && isset($_POST['URL']) && isset($_POST['VideoDate'])) {
....
}
```

This is basic programming stuff, so you might want to get a good introductory book to programming or PHP.