# One PHP Script with two PDO queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

I've recently starting using PDO in a rebuild of a client's taxi booking system.

I have a script called create_booking.php, which initially inserts the booking details into a bookings table in the MySQL database. After inserting the customers details it retrieves the lastinsertID to get the booking ref. It then creates a job in the jobs table and references the booking reference to relate the job/booking.

The first insert is working fine, but the second insert isn't . Any ideas?

```
    if (isset($_POST['customer_title'])) {

  include('../assets/db_connection.php');

  $create_booking = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings(customer_name, billing_address,    contact_tel, contact_mob, contact_email, party_pax, party_cases, booking_notes, price, booking_agent, booking_date, booking_status, authorised)
                                      VALUES(:customer_name, :billing_address, :contact_tel, :contact_mob, :contact_email, :party_pax, :party_cases, :booking_notes, :price, :booking_agent, :booking_date, :booking_status, :authorised );");
  $create_booking->execute(array(
      ":customer_name"       =>   $customer_title  . ' ' .   $customer_first_name  . ' '  .   $customer_last_name,
      ":billing_address"     =>   $billing_address,
      ":contact_tel"         =>   $customer_tel,
      ":contact_mob"         =>   $customer_mobile,
      ":contact_email"       =>   $customer_email,
      ":party_pax"           =>   $passengers,
      ":party_cases"         =>   $cases,
      ":booking_notes"       =>   $booking_notes,
      ":price"               =>   $price,
      ":booking_agent"       =>   $booking_agent,
      ":booking_date"        =>   $booking_date,
      ":booking_status"      =>   $booking_status,
      ":authorised"          =>   $authorised    
    ));

  $booking_ref = $db->lastInsertId('booking_ref'); // Takes Booking Ref generated in $create_booking

  $create_job    = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO jobs(booking_ref, pickup_date, pickup_time, pickup_address, destination_address, return, scheduled)
                                (:booking_ref, :pickup_date, :pickup_time, :pickup_address, :destination_address, :return, :scheduled )");

  $create_job->execute(array(

      ":booking_ref"          =>  $booking_ref,
      ":pickup_date"          =>  $pickup_date,
      ":pickup_time"          =>  $pickup_time,
      ":pickup_address"       =>  $pickup_address,
      ":destination_address"  =>  $pickup_destination,
      ":return"               =>  "N",
      ":scheduled"            =>  "N"

    ));

}
```

Comment: What is the error on the second one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: @djdy thanks for your reply, I'm not getting any errors, which is what confuses me. It just isn't inserting. It seems like the script is ending after the first insert.

Comment: Is $booking_ref definitely getting a value? Also, is the table structure 100% correct? i.e. You're not trying to insert a string into an INT column? Or skipping some required columns?

Comment: I've echoed $booking_ref and it is returning the correct value, i've defaulted everything to VARCHAR on the database to make sure no interference there and still having the same issue :/

Comment: Does the second command run through on its own (comment out the first command and give a dummy value for `$booking_ref`)?

Comment: @anton I've commented out the first insert as you said, the second insert still won't execute. I've even dropped the table and re-created it to make sure nothing strange was going on there. Can't understand what is wrong with the second insert.

Comment: It may be something wrong with the values being inserted. Could you post the fields and their respective datatypes, and then the exact values that don't insert from your PHP code (maybe use var_dump())?

Answer (score 2):

Your second SQL query is missing `VALUES`.

`INSERT INTO() ... VALUES()`

`$create_job    = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO jobs(booking_ref, pickup_date, pickup_time, pickup_address, destination_address, return, scheduled)
VALUES                                (:booking_ref, :pickup_date, :pickup_time, :pickup_address, :destination_address, :return, :scheduled )");`

Comment: How embarrassing, oh well they always say you cant spot your own mistakes. Thanks

Comment: I've put the VALUES back in to the code, and I'm having the same problem, still no errors, first insert working fine, second been ignored.

Comment: Please see my follow up comment on the question itself.