# MySQL query working in phpmyadmin but not in php with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

When i run this query in `phpmyadmin` it runs fine and returns what it should return.
When i run it in `php` with `PDO` it fails. Can someone tell me why? The error message shows that the right parameters were used.

Code i run in `phpmyadmin`.

```
SELECT  `fd1`.`id` ,  `fd2`.`id` ,  `fd3`.`id` 
FROM  `food` AS  `fd1` ,  `food` AS  `fd2` ,  `food` AS  `fd3` 
WHERE  `fd1`.`food` =  'Empty'
AND  `fd2`.`food` =  'Carrot'
AND  `fd3`.`food` =  'Empty'
```

Code i run in `php`

```
$sql = 'SELECT  `fd1`.`id` ,  `fd2`.`id` ,  `fd3`.`id` 
        FROM  `food` AS  `fd1` ,  `food` AS  `fd2` ,  `food` AS  `fd3` 
        WHERE  `fd1`.`food` = ? 
        AND  `fd2`.`food` = ? 
        AND  `fd3`.`food` = ?'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $food1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $food2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $food3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();


if (!$stmt->rowCount())
    die("ERROR:FOOD_SEARCH_FAILURE food:$food1, $food2, $food3 rows returned". $stmt->rowCount());
```

I also tried to run it with:

```
$stmt->execute(array($food1, $food2, $food3));
```

Same results

Comment: You are 100000% sure $food1 is Empty, $food2 is Carrot, and so on? Does the query succeed? (see [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: It doesn't have to be Empty, Carrot, Empty, it can be any combination of values that are stored in the table. I used various values, and in `phpmyadmin` it works, in `php` it doesn't

Comment: After the execute, use errorInfo() to see the error

Comment: What's the PDO error message?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

Comment: @Pekka I hardcoded the values, 'Empty', 'Cherries", 'Empty' in `php` code so i can be 100000% sure, and same results.

Comment: try{}catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getTraceAsString();}

Comment: @ArunKillu that's unnecessary. Uncaught error will be shown as well.

Comment: @DeusDeceit is that array the values array?

Comment: @DeusDeceit what happens, if you put instead of question marks the real values? I mean like the query you execute in phpmyadmin without having to bind params

Comment: can you post the mysql log with the corresponding entries?

Comment: `it runs fine and returns what it should return`
...what returns?

Comment: rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement for most databases [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: @Amir 
21 2 21 <--<< This is what it returns.

Comment: @david strachan... seems like you're right. Now I feel embarrassed. Put that as an answer pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement for most databases
[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: For mysql it could be an issue only in case of ancient version of PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't quite understand why it should be an issue only for ancient versions? Obviously it is always an issue, since `rowCount` returns the number of affected (deleted/updated/inserted but not selected) rows!

Answer (score 1):

First, connect to PDO the way described in the [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) and set error reporting **on** to be sure you will see any error occurred.
Make an **intentional** error in the query to test if you can see them.

Next, if no errors anyway - check your data, both in database and bound variables (there is nowhere in your code you define them)