# PHP PDO cannot connect to remote host

Tags: php, mysql

i have to connect to a mysql server from php program using pdo, problem is i cannot get it connected from php but i can connect it with same configuration using other SQL Managers.

```
parent::__construct('mysql'.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: nothing to be precise. blank page.

Comment: 1) this question is not for SO, as there is no programming component involved, 2) if PHP connects from a remote server while the other managers connect from your local machine, the MySql configuration might treat these connection attempts differently.

Comment: [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: Try to use try and catch to see what exceptions appear. Also, try to see if value of the variable uses is correct.

Comment: If you're going to try catch an exception, don't forget you need to set PDO's error reporting to Exceptions.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server. Error message