# insert does not success using pdo for database

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Here I am trying to insert into db without sql injection. Things are ok as per me still not getting inserted into table:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$uname = $_POST['name'];
$myid = $_POST['myid'];

$user='root';
$pass='root';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1:3306', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO user_record (id,uname,email) VALUES (:id, :uname, :email)');
$stmt->bindParam(':uname', $uname);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $myid);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

$stmt->execute();
```

Can someone point what's wrong.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without an error message or detail about what is wrong or what you've tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3726526/285587

Comment: @ChrisLively: No error. But when i see in table. data does not get inserted@

Comment: Are you sure it's actually hitting the table you expect?  Have you tried running that insert query directly to see what error, if any, has occurred?  Have you tested the result from the `$stmt->execute();` code to see if it's a true or false?  One way to get the error back would be to call `$dbErr = $stmt->errorInfo();` immediately after the execute.  I could certainly see this failing if `id` was an auto increment field...

Comment: @ChrisLively care to click a link above?

Comment: @YourCommonSense:  Not really; but you might elaborate here, to the OP, why that link is pertinent.

Answer (score -1):

```
 new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

First comes the host after comes the db.