# How to do a PHP PDO insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert in to a database using PDO.

Here is my code:

```
$SQLinsert = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO `sites` VALUES(NULL, :site, :username)");
$SQLinsert -> execute(array(':site' => $site, ':username' => $user));
```

I added the PDO error reporting and I get this error:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

Comment: Aren't the field names obligatory? Otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: You can leave out the field names in MySQL.  It assumes you are passing in all the fields in the order they are defined in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDO doesn't give error messages when the SQL is wrong. You can use [`errorInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to get SQL errors:

```
if ($SQLinsert -> execute(array(':site' => $site, ':username' => $user))) {
    // ok
} else {
    print_r($odb->errorInfo());
}
```

My guess on your SQL by the way is that you have more columns than those three. If that's the case, add the column names to make it work:

```
INSERT INTO `sites` (col1, site, username) VALUES(NULL, :site, :username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use   php try catch block  with [get_message()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php) method.

```
  try{ 
        $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `sites` VALUES(NULL, :site, :username)");
        $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':site' => $site, ':username' => $user));
    } 
    catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        print  $exception->getMessage(); 
    }
```

Or you need following [attribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) in your db connection

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```