# I'm having an issue with my PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I get when I attempt to use my log in form. My PHP, HTML, and error is listed below

PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("h","h","h","g");
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND  pwd=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST["username"], $_POST["pwd"]);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows == 1)
{
    echo "you are logged in";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username"required>
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="pwd"required>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/u378761662/public_html/login/login.php on line 5
```

Comment: Your prepare() call is failing. See [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: Consider removing your credentials (Database User/Pass).

Comment: This is minor, but you should use the `mysqli` constructor instead of the `mysqli_connect` wrapper: `$con = new mysqli("h", "h", "h", "g");`.

Comment: @mc10 no he does not, it is just an alias.

Comment: @Class So just change it to 'pwd != password'?

Comment: @Mustafa "Should", not "must". The constructor just makes it a bit clearer that you are left with a `mysqli` object.

Comment: @Class So just change the stuff on line 3?

Comment: you have `SELECT password` then you use `pwd=?` they should be the same name.

Comment: @Class I just updated it and tried it out, but still get the same error

Comment: @Pekka웃 Tried that an the issue wasn't resolved

Comment: Your prepare() call is failing and the question linked above should be getting an error message telling you what went wrong.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I inserted the code and i'm not getting any error message other then the one I already have

Comment: did you set `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`?

Comment: Can you edit the full code you have now into the question?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The code above is still the code in question

Comment: So you didn't change anything at all?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I added the code to retrieve the error message on my file and removed it since it wasn't a help. Is there any way you could edit the code to help me out fix the issue?

Comment: You will need to know what goes wrong in order to be able to fix whatever the issue is, so put the error handling code back to see whether there's something wrong with it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I put it back in, Now what?

Comment: Oh, you are using mysqli. That's the wrong code for that, sorry. Try `echo $con->error` after the line where you call `$con->prepare();`

Comment: @Pekka웃 This is what I get now **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u378761662/public_html/login/login.php on line 6**

Comment: You need to add a semicolon at the end of each command

Comment: @Pekka웃 So like this? **$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST["username"]; $_POST["pwd"]);**

Comment: No after the `echo $con->error`

Comment: @Pekka웃 I now get this above the prior error. My table does exist btw **Table 'u378761662_user.users' doesn't exist**

Comment: There's your problem then.

Comment: My table is called "user" and I entered it as "user" but it gives me the **user.users** In the error code

Comment: You are saying `SELECT username, password FROM users `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an exception is thrown on `login.php` at the line no: 5.

Add `echo $con->error;` before `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST["username"], $_POST["pwd"]);` and see if it throws an error.

Hope this helps.