# PHP PDO Insert query with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to run an sql query using PDO prepared statements

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (ticketnumber, status) VALUES (1234, Open) ";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

But it is just not inserting. What have I done wrong?

Here is my connection:

```
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}", $username, $password);
```

Comment: Tried copying that code to your db and see what happens?

Comment: SQL loves single-quotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: See also [MySQL when to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: This isn't really a prepared statement; the values to be inserted should be `:ticketnumber :status` and then provided.

Comment: You have a db with empty name??

Comment: @Mihai also empty username and password!!! Come on now.

Comment: I didn't want to put the connection details on here! Surely it's a little obvious!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It's much more secure.
Make sure you have included your connection file.

**EDITED**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tickets` (ticketnumber, status) VALUES (:ticketnumber, :status)";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':ticketnumber', 1234, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':status', 'Open', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also, the named parameters used above must **NOT** be enclosed in quotes. If you do so, it'll be treated as a literal string and not a named parameter.

Comment: So for every column and value I have to bind the value ?

Comment: how come it is more secure?

Comment: @charlie of course not. for the values that are coming from variables only.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If he's using it as it is, it might be prone to SQL Injections right? Assuming its a variable containing user input. Because inserting data like this manually is not always used.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use quotes on strings before inserting them into a database.
2. Why use prepare if you're not preparing your data before sending it to the database?