# Cannot connect to database using pdo

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in index.php

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bonacadb', 'zokam', '********');
}
catch (Exception $exc)
{
    die('Database error, likely file not found or a permissions problem.');
}
```

I got:

```
Database error, likely file not found or a permissions problem.
```

I created database using phpMyAdmin. Any help ?

Comment: And did you set up the right permissions for the user?

Comment: `echo $exc->getMessage();` is your friend.

Comment: A fixed error message like that is useless, especially when PDO can tell you what the problem is: `die($exc->getMessage());`

Comment: If you're going to make up the reason it failed yourself, at least make it good.  `die('Database error, user is way too sexy to run this query.');`

Comment: @MarcB, I changed the line and got `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'zokam'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. What should I do, pls ?

Comment: @bonaca Start here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQLSTATE+Access+denied+for+user+

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using,

Also put the db name before the ip.

```
try{
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=database123;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'yourusername';
    $pass = 'yourpassword';

    $dbc = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $dbc->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
}
```

thanks
JR

Answer (score 2):

How about trying like this?

```
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bonacadb', 'zokam', 'zokam1405');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection error: ".$e->getMessage(); exit;
}
```