# Why is the database not updating in this?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this php:

```
<?php 
    $db= new PDO("mysql:host=example;dbname=example", "root", "example");
    $query= $db->prepare("SELECT yarnName, price, sale_price, cost, contents, onSale, yarnLink, yarnImage, activeFlag FROM yarn WHERE yarnId = :parameter");
    $query->bindParam(':parameter', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $salePrice=$_POST['salePrice'];
    $cost=$_POST['cost'];
    $contents=$_POST['contents'];
    $onSale=$_POST['onSale'];
    $yarnLink=$_POST['yarnLink'];
    $image=$_POST['image'];
    $active=$_POST['active'];
    $attrUpdates= array($name,$price,$salePrice,$cost,$contents,$onSale,$yarnLink,$image,$active);
    $attrOriginal=$query->fetch();
    if(count($attrUpdates)==count($attrOriginal)){
        for($i=0; $i<count($attrUpdates); $i++){
            if($attrUpdate[$i]!=$attrOriginal[$i]&&$attrUpdate[$i]!=null){
                switch($i){
                    case 0:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET yarnName = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 1:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET price = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 2:     
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET sale_price = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 3:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET cost = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 4:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET contents = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 5:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET onSale = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 6:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET yarnLink = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 7:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET yarnImage = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                    case 8:
                        $update=$db->prepare("UPDATE yarn SET activeFlag = :parameter1 WHERE yarnId = :parameter2");
                }
                $query->bindParam(':parameter1', $attrUpdate[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':parameter2', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

and it is not updating the database.  I'm not sure as to why this is, but if anyone tell me what's wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I don't think it's the post where it's going wrong, but it could be.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: echo the variables that have the posted values, log any database errors and used the web console to observe the http requests. That last one isn't really much, but it says the post was a success.

Comment: You'll need to start with some systematic debugging to narrow it down.  Look at [How to squeeze an error message out of PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo) .

Comment: By default, PDO errors silently (except for the initial connection, which throws an exception).  Set it up to throw exceptions all the time.

Comment: a try-catch statement on the query->execute() can show your problem more than sure

Comment: @HellBaby Not in the code's current state.  `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` must first be set.

Comment: What is the value of `$id` here: `$query->bindParam(':parameter', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: the value of $id is 2, which is correct.  I'm a little confused with all the setting PDO error stuff, and I'll try the try catch.

Comment: I am getting this `Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.` when the file input is left blank, which then the post does not work.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what you need to know. In order for files to be uploaded by a file input, and metadata appear in `$_FILES` in PHP, you must set the enctype correctly in your form.  `<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'.....>`

Comment: Yeah I got that, I just didn't know if that would stop things or not.

Answer (score 0):

$query change to $update

```
$update->bindParam(':parameter1', $attrUpdate[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->bindParam(':parameter2', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->execute();
```

Comment: Please always point out what you're changing and why.  "try this" answers aren't always as helpful as they seem when the problem is subtle as an incorrect variable used.

Comment: oh yeah, I meant to write that actually, I just copied that query part from an old script, thanks for pointing it out.