# PHP PDO: Can not display mysql data in drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, fatal-error

I am trying to get a column from mysql database into a drop down list but the following error is displaying every time.
Code:

```
<?php  
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "root";  
$db_password = "root";  
$db_name = "my_database";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<form action="members.php" method="POST">
    <select name='access_country' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <?
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Country FROM AccessNumbers"); //Line No: 362
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<option value=".$row['Country'].">".$row['Country']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Following error is displaying:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line 362
```

Comment: where do you create the $dbh object?

Comment: thats on top of the page....i haven't pasted all the code on the page.

Comment: Can you show the connection statement?

Comment: Please show the FULL code

Comment: Apart from `$dbh` not being an object, why do you use a prepared statement that has no parameters? That should be a query, not prepared statement.

Comment: See [how to squeeze an error message out of PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo). By default, it errors silently. Set it up to throw exceptions, and you'll more easily see what went wrong.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: It does have error handler, i have just updated the code.

Comment: You are certain you didn't see another error from the initial `try/catch`? And you are certain that you didn't overwrite `$dbh` somewhere else in code not posted?  If the connection failed initially, your `catch` block would have executed and you would see an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea what exactly the problem was.
I simply restarted my MAMP server and accessed the page. And it was working.