# Inserting values into database using PDO-mysql

Tags: php, database, pdo, mysqli

When I execute my, mysql query to database using PDO-mysql it will not insert the values. I am following the documentation but still don't seem to have made any progress.

So my .sql file is this

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `qr_db`; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qr_db`.`clients` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `key` char(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

grant select, insert, update, delete 
on qr_db.* 
to qr_db@localhost identified by 'password';
```

and this is the code I'm having trouble with

```
if(!isset($_GET['key'])) {

$mysql = db_connect();  // <--- this is ok i already checked this

$query = 'INSERT INTO `clients` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `hash`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $mysql->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindParam(1, $f_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $l_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $dubhash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: what does `$stmt->errorInfo()` give you?

Comment: please check any of your `php variable` you used for `binding` must not be blank.. and if it is so.. than you have to put `allow null` in your particular table field...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: errorInfo() didn't print anything

Comment: check this answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034205/inserting-values-into-database-using-pdo-mysql/22034468#22034468

Comment: you really want this script to happen when `$_GET['key']` is **not** set?

Answer (score -1):

First check your connection if you connected with the database then use following the code 
to insert the record

Change hash in column name to key. this is creating problem because table don't have any column with name hash

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, key) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :hashval)";

$q = $mysql->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':fname'=>$f_name,
                  ':lname'=>$lname,
                  ':hashval'=>$hash ));
```

Best of Luck...

Comment: First have to be a comment and second adds nothing to what tha OP have now

Comment: did you changed "hash" with "key" in query? INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, key)?

Comment: ok i did that , still not working though . this is odd i have done this hundreds of times but just not with PDO

Comment: I think there is problem with your database connection... Did you check that?

Comment: Yes I did the database connection is fine

Comment: When I look into the database i see that the table `clients` is MyISAM and the sum is InnoDB . I'm not sure if that the issue or not .

Comment: I think you should create the table again and just use create table command. Use only this is part.CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qr_db`.`clients` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `key` char(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`)
)