# PDO not throwing errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code to insert a new record in a database:

```
<?php

require('comune.php');
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$segreto = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($segreto);
$validity = $_POST['validity'];
$ruolo = $_POST['ruolo'];
$funzione = $_POST['funzione'];
list($giorno, $mese, $anno) = explode('/', $validity);
$validity = implode('-', array($anno, $mese, $giorno));

try {
    $sql = "INSERT into utenti "
            . "(nome,username,segreto,password,validity,ruolo,funzione) "
            . "VALUES ('$nome', '$username', '$segreto', '$password', '$validity', '$ruolo', '$funzione')";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $message = "ko";
}
$message = "ok";
//echo $sql;
echo $message;
?>
```

The issue I am facing is that, even if the query returns an error, $message is "ok". What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You're overwriting the `$message` variable, so the output will always be `ok`.

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: @meagar I know but this is just a sample code to show the issue

Comment: Amal has it right... $message will ALWAYS be ok, because you are doing that before the echo, regardless of an error or not.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Amal is right. It's just a matter of overwriting the $message variable. Thanks anyway for the link.

Comment: Put your `$message = "ok"` before the `try catch` block. This way, by default `$message` is `ok`. If error is generated, it is overwritten.

Comment: You should also consider *meaningful* error messages like `$e->getMessage()` instead of `'ko'`.

Comment: yes. I know. This code is just to give a representation of the issue I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
$sql = "INSERT into utenti (nome,username,segreto,password,validity,ruolo,funzione) "
        . "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->execute([$nome, $username, $segreto, $password, $validity, $ruolo, $funzione]);
echo "ok";
```

you will have either ok or informative error message

Comment: it is better to keep the try catch block: in the catch loop I have added $message="ko"; echo $message; exit(); and everything is ok

Comment: @LelioFaieta it is not better. there is no point in echoing ok and there is no point in  exit(); there should be either HTTP redirect on success or 500 error on error

Comment: your ajax should recognize HTTP response code. if it's different from 200, then it's error. For some strange reason you imagine that only PDO can cause an error, while it can be ANY code. At the same time full error message have to be LOGGED, instead of echoing useless ko