# Insertion using PDO php

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I will admit I am a newbie when it comes to PDO, but I have to change over a form that is in mysql.. I am getting connection, but nothing inserted.. I am truly stuck and feel like an idiot because I know it is something simple I am missing

I have tried having the arrays above and after the insert.. Neither work

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my code:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);


$STH = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO PinTrade (ID, PIN, Year, Make, Model, Mileage, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Date)
VALUES ('', '$pin', '$year', '$make', '$model', '$mileage', '$first', '$last', '$phone', '$email', '1234' )");
$STH->bindParam(':PIN', $_POST['pin']);
$STH->bindParam(':Year', $_POST['year']);
$STH->bindParam(':Make', $_POST['make']);   
$STH->bindParam(':Model', $_POST['model']); 
$STH->bindParam(':Mileage', $_POST['mileage']); 
$STH->bindParam(':FirstName', $_POST['first']); 
$STH->bindParam(':LastName', $_POST['last']);
$STH->bindParam(':Phone', $_POST['phone']); 
$STH->bindParam(':Email', $_POST['email']);
$STH->execute();
```

Comment: first and foremost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: You need to change all values to bindParam() handles - not '$model' but :model in your query.

Comment: But your problem is quite a silly one: you are using PDO wrong way. What tutorial you are learning from?

Comment: @Your Common Sense Apparently bad ones :) I started back in the era of dinos using ColdFusion, so I should have a better grasp.. but I stumbling through it until I get it.. Any pointers or tuts you can list would be great!

Comment: I can't believe any tutorial would tell you to add variables into query directly. did you try from tuts+ one?

Comment: The variables are on me.. they were a carry over from the old form.. I forgot to change them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the dollar signs and quotes in your query values:

```
$STH = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO PinTrade (ID, PIN, Year, Make,
                        Model, Mileage,        FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Date)
                       VALUES (null, :PIN, :Year, :Make, //and so on....
```

Also note, assuming ID is an auto incrementing field, just insert null

```
  VALUES (null, :PIN,
```

Finally, if you're pulling from the post array, I'd use `bindValue` over  `bindParam`

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped.. I truly, truly appreciate it!!