# Querying PDO with OCI

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have set up everything to work with PDO_OCI. I have made a connection too.
But as soon as I try to fetch something it returns false or null always:

```
$selectBla = "SELECT bla,bla,bla
                                 FROM bla
                                 WHERE blabla = ?
                                 AND bla = ?";
$parameters = array($_POST['bla'], $_POST['bla']);
$query = $db->prepare($selectBla);
$query->execute($parameters);
$userRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Does anybody have a idea? Does it have to do with OCI_PDO?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo

Comment: PDO does not display errors by default. That's true no matter the driver.

Comment: seems fine to me. maybe you don't have data... can we see some true data?

Comment: Thanks this showed me some helpful errors `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to see the error messages and I got one after that I easily solved the problem.

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```