# How can I alter NLS_DATE_FORMAT in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

How can I alter the NLS_DATE_FORMAT from an Oracle database using PDO.
So far I have this:

```
    $date_set = "DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS";
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("ALTER SESSION SET 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' = ?");
    $query->execute(array($date_set));
```

But when I try to fetch the session:

```
    $query = "select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT'";
    $parameters = array();
    $test = $this->fetchRow($query, $parameters);
    var_dump($test); exit();
```

it returns:

DD-MON-RR"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
ALTER SESSION SET 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

... should trigger this error:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

If you cannot detect it, there's an issue in your error checking code. Most likely, [you haven't configured PDO to throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo).

The problem is that `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not a string but an identifier:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Answer (score 2):

In my system, setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT have no effect, maybe because I used oracle instant client. The cure for my system is to add another alter session command :

```
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';
```

It seems that the OCI driver got confused when NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set and NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE is unset, and reverting to the DD-MON-RR format.

Answer (score 0):

When using PHP/PDO/Oracle you can use:

```
//change settings below
$username='user';
$password='mypassword';
$dbname='databasename';
$hostname='localhost';
$port='1521';
$sid='XE'; //could also be ORCL
$charset='WE8ISO8859P1'; //or UTF8 or whatever charset
$oraclelangauge='AMERICAN';

$tns = "(DESCRIPTION = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ".$hostname.")(PORT = ".$port."))
      (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ".$sid.")(SERVER = DEDICATED)))";

$dbDB = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns.";charset=".$charset, $username, $password);
$result = $dbDB->query("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = '".$oraclelanguage."'");
```

Be sure to have *php_pdo_oci* extension enabled and first double check your Oracle connection settings with a different Oracle client like SQL Developer.

Also first check if `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = <language>` is working, for the *$oraclelanguage* setting you have set, in an Oracle client.