# How to change default date format in Oracle DB with trunc?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

I have two separate databases.

When I run a query on 1st db:

```
select
      TO_DATE( sysdate , 'YY-MM-DD')- 1 / 86400 data1,
      trunc(sysdate, 'dd') data2,
      to_char( sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') date3
from dual
```

it returns this result:

```
    [data1] => 14/07/02
    [data2] => 14/07/02
    [date3] => 2014-07-02
```

When I run this same query on 2nd db:

```
select
      TO_DATE( sysdate , 'YY-MM-DD')- 1 / 86400 data1,
      trunc(sysdate, 'dd') data2,
      to_char( sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') date3
from dual
```

returns me results like below

```
    [data1] => 14-JUL-02
    [data2] => 02-JUL-14
    [date3] => 2014-07-02
```

How I can change response from DB2 with OCI to return date format like DB1?

Connection string to DB1

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('oci:dbname='.User::db1()->hostfullspec, User::db1()->login, User::db1()->passwd);
    $pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
    $pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     die("ORA RAP: PDO CONNECTION ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() ).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Connection string to DB2

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('oci:dbname='.User::db2()->hostfullspec, User::db2()->login, User::db2()->passwd);
    $pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
    $pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     die("ORA RAP: PDO CONNECTION ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do an

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yy-mm-dd';
```

Also, the code

```
TO_DATE( sysdate , 'YY-MM-DD')- 1 / 86400 data1,
```

should be

```
to_char(sysdate - 1/86400, 'YY-MM-DD') data1,
```

or, if you set the NLS, just

```
sysdate - 1/86400 data1,
```

Answer (score 0):

See [How can I alter NLS_DATE_FORMAT in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860101/how-can-i-alter-nls-date-format-in-php)
so the answer is something like

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YY-MM-DD';