# Pdo insert into table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have started to move me from using the typical outdated mysql to use the PDO extension.

Could someone helped me fix the following code? It has no error messages, but it will obviously not insert a new table in my database. 
the database is used, varchar, and key is also varchar.

```
  $id = 1;
$used = '1x2';
$load = $get->prepare("INSERT INTO keys (key,used) VALUES (:id,:used)");
$load->bindValue(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$load->bindValue(':used',$used, PDO::PARAM_STR);


try {
$load->execute();
}catch(exception $e) {
echo 'Error';
echo errorhandle($e);
}
```

Comment: `key` and `keys` are reserved words http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - either rename those or use backticks.

Comment: Read over [How to squeeze an error message out of PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo) and setup `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. By default, PDO _errors silently_.

Comment: oh, i will check it out. Talk about bad luck that I chose that name: p

Comment: I updated the code itself no, still wont work now even after my variablechanges.

Comment: @Malin what variable changes?  Your query needs to look like `INSERT INTO \`keys\` (\`key\`,used) VALUES (:key,:used)` (note the backticks around key, keys)

Comment: it should be possible to use NSERT INTO keys (key,used) VALUES (:key,:used) somehow? since in mysql i got inserted rows to key easily.

Comment: @Malin Ok, I see the changes above. It isn't the placeholder `:key` that is your problem, it is the column name `key` and the table name `keys`. Those need to be quoted with backticks as in my example above.

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, replacing `$pdo` with your DB connection, see if it yields anything.

Comment: See also [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) for quoting samples...

Comment: i see @MichaelBerkowski, but it still wont work :/

Comment: I'm questioning `errorhandle($e)` I doubt that's a core function.

Comment: @Fred-ii-

added it and it throwed out:

ErrorSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (`key`,used) VALUES ('1','1x2')' at line 1

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the function errorhandle($e) works fine, it threw out error. http://malinpedersen.no/PDO/index.php

Comment: @Malin That means you haven't added the backticks around the two reserved words as in my comment from ~5 minutes ago. `\`keys\`` and `\`key\``

Comment: I stand corrected then.

Comment: $load = $get->prepare("INSERT INTO keys (`key`,used) VALUES (:`key`,:used)");

Comment: `keys` needs backticks too for the INSERT INTO. `key` and `keys` but not backticks for the placeholders leave it as `:key`

Comment: @Fred-ii-

thanks, now i understood it. Im not currently familiar with these words that i cant use, since in the old mysql_query i did use ` and 's on everything. fixed.

Comment: You're welcome, glad this has been resolved, cheers.