# Database insert not working (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP that basically is being used for inserting an email and password into an SQL database:

```
<?php  
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
require "database.php";
$message = '';

  if (!empty($_POST["email"]) &&!empty($_POST["password"])):
  //Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if ($stmt->execute() ):

      $message = 'Successfully created a new user';
    else:
      $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue whilst registering';
    endif;

  endif;
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-6">
  <div class="container text-center">
  <?php if (!empty($message)):
  ?>
  <h3 id="h3message"><?= $message ?> </h3>
<?php endif; ?>
     <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter your email" name="email"> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
          <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="confirm_password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't insert into the database (all the fields, variables are correct i think - just email and password) and it comes back with the error message that I created that says 'Sorry there must have been an issue whilst registering'

Here is the database.php file

```
<?php 

$server =  'localhost';
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "auth";

try{
  $conn = new PDO ("mysql:host={$server};dbname={$database};" , $username, $password);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
  die ( "Connection failed; " . $e->getMessage());
} 

?>
```

Comment: Please, check [PDO::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). You might want to [get PDO to provide the errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Comment: Your code works on my setup as it is (i only need to change the mysql credentials). Are you absolutely sure that your root user does not have a password?

Comment: Sidenote: you aren't using the `confirm_password` field server-side.

Comment: Yes the root user does not have a password

Comment: I haven't set up the confirm_password just yet, trying to get this to work first

Comment: Add the following var_dump($stmt->errorInfo()); just before $message = 'Sorry...'; and share what the error message was

Comment: 1 => int 1366
  2 => string 'Incorrect integer value: '$2y$10$sQnVR0FK0uSGLypUq95GrOrFWQYrd3rlSbsNiQgo2cOmDCd/jKvaO' for column 'password' at row 1' (length=118)

Comment: You password column in the database, change it to VARCHAR 255 and try again. It seems that its currently set as an integer and can only take numbers

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work

Comment: Are you still getting the incorrect integer value error?

Comment: Could you share your table structure?

Comment: yes i do still get the error, and here https://gyazo.com/e869d63986d4e64d07fddc0e12c3fb66

Comment: Until you change the password field from int(200) to varchar(255) you will not be able to store the password into the database. The table structure you shared indicates that the password field is an int field.

Comment: thanks it worked! sometimes i wonder where my head is at

Answer (score 0):

Hash the password before you bind it:

```
$UserPWHash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$stmt->bindParam(":password", $UserPWHash));
```

Comment: I changed it to: $UserPWHash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $UserPWHash));                                but still doesn't work

Comment: Not hashing the password initially did not prevent the entry from saving. It raised a notice, but it didn't prevent inserting the record.