# Using $_POST to insert into MySQL db w/ PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a Pastebin-esque project on my free time and it only recently hit me that I need to have a title for the pastes. I'm using PDO, and I pretty much had to redo the entire php script that inserts already, and now I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's the body of my HTML to begin with, paste.html:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    Title: <input type="text" name="title">
    <br>
    Paste: <br> <input type="text" name="paste">
    <input type="submit" value="insert">
</form>
```

And here's my insert.php:

```
require 'connection.php';

$paste = $_POST['paste'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO pasteinfo (title, paste) VALUES (:title, :paste)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':paste', $paste);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->execute();
$con = null;
```

I really don't know what's wrong here. Thanks!

EDIT: connection.php looks like this:

```
try {
    $con = new pdo("mysql:host='';dbname='pastes'",'','','pasteinfo');
    echo "connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: turn on error reporting on both PHP and PDO

Comment: Can you show the contents of `connection.php`?

Comment: @Irvin <?php
 try {
 $con = new pdo("mysql:host='';dbname=pastes",'','','pastes');
 echo "connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
 echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?> Seems like I have two 'pastes' in there, didn't notice that til reading through it for like the 80th time now lol. Could that be the issue?

Comment: So what is the `username`,`password`, and `host` you are using?

Comment: @Ghost My connection.php which I posted above a few moments ago has it. Didn't get any errors until I tried removing the second 'pastes'. How do I turn it on for PHP?

Comment: @Irvin root account on a VPS of mine.

Comment: I think the problem is in the `$con = new pdo...` part.

Comment: @Irvin it worked before I tried to implement 'title'. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Possibly the table?

Comment: @Irvin Sorry, but which part of the new pdo statement is the table?

Comment: I mean your table in the database. Schema? Sometimes those little things are harder to debug.

Comment: @Irvin http://pastebin.com/SAPx5fkq Is that what you mean? Sorry, I'm a little new to this aha.

Comment: @index.php [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/how-to-squeeze-error-message-out-of-pdo)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like that:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':paste', $paste, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

Where the third param is the data type and the fourth is the length.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: Remove colon (:)
`$stmt->bindParam('paste', $paste, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->bindParam('title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);`

Comment: @SebCar Having the same issue still.

Comment: Have you tried to catch the error in execution of the stmt?
`$paste = $_POST['paste'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pasteinfo (title, paste) VALUES (:title, :paste)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':paste', $paste);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->execute();}
   catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
   }
    $con = null;`

Comment: @SebCar That's interesting. I have not, but when I did instead of displaying the usual "connected successfully" message nothing was displayed. However, when I tried refreshing it (after removing the code you asked me to put in) I realized that I didn't get a POST prompt, but when your code was in I did?

Comment: So, you do not get any errors?  You can also see the number of affected rows using this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @SebCar yeah. But with my whole post thing, does that mean that the HTML is the issue?

Comment: @SebCar    $stmt->bindParam('title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $count = $stmt->rowcount();
  print($count); Didn't get any response.

Comment: but you need to put these inside try to see what is going on. The html is fine I think.

Comment: @SebCar what do you mean?

Comment: You need to use the code I put in the comment (try...) to see whats the error

Comment: @SebCar Added try to my code for the error thing, didn't get any errors again. My bad for misreading that.

Comment: try to use echo or var_dump to know if that part of the code is reached

Comment: @SebCar put an echo just above $con = null; with no response.

Comment: Have you tried to check if the request method is POST using: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` ?