# Delete Table Row on Button Click Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, sql-delete

I have an HTML table that has 4 columns: SKU Group, Group_ID, Edit button, and Delete button. I am working on the delete function now and want it so that whenever I press the delete button, a confirmation box pops up and then if "OK" is pressed, it deletes the row and sends a delete query which deletes it from the database.

I know I am to use Ajax and a separate PHP script for the delete query, but cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

HTML for Delete Button:

```
<td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
```

JavaScript...I know this needs some work but am posting it for the sake of my question:

```
function deleteRow(r) {

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("skuTable").deleteRow(i);
  }



    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete.php",
      data: i
    });


        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row deleted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to delete");
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


}
```

delete.php:

```
<?php

  $SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];
  $Group_ID = $_POST['Group_ID'];

  $host="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $delete = "DELETE FROM SKU_Group_Dim WHERE Group_ID = '$Group_ID'";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($delete);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);
  if(!$result) {
      echo json_encode(sqlsrv_errors());
  }

?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: This looks like you're on the right track, what isn't working?

Comment: Your data variable in ajax doesn't have the parameters corresponding to your $_POST getters from the looks of things.

Comment: @LoveenDyall Yes I knew that was for sure a problem, I just didnt know what should go there

Comment: Whatever you name the $_POST parameters, you should url_encode the same parameter string. so data: "Group_ID="+i; or something similar

Comment: @JayBlanchard if i click the delete button, the confirmation box pops up and my row goes away....however if i reload the page, the row comes right back so a delete query is never actually sent to the database

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes this is being run on a web server. And yes i do get an error - "Unexpected token in JSON"

Comment: Ah! You need to figure out what that is. It is likely because a DELETE query doesn't really return anything.

Comment: I have no idea what it would be...how can I find out?

Comment: Have you confirmed `$_POST['Group_ID'];` is being passed correctly? It sounds like the query is failing and consequently you're getting back errors. Just echo the error instead of trying to `json_encode()` because the error being returned is not an array which can be encoded.

Comment: I just tried `echo json_encode($Group_ID)` and `echo $Group_ID` and got an unexpected token error each time

Comment: I got rid of the `json_encode` and just did the echo on the errors and there is no unexpected token error anymore. It just says row failed to delete, thats all

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$_POST` is popoulated? Place a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of the page and then run your AJAX call. Look in the browser's developer tools and make sure the array is populated.

Comment: I placed it at the top of the page, ran my ajax call, and nothing is being displayed so im guessing that the $_POST is not populated then??

Answer (score 3):

**JavaScript**

First, I noticed you are using jQuery so why not try utilizing it to its full potential?

Start by creating an `onclick` event handler for your `.delete` buttons.

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    // do something when delete button is clicked
});
```

You only want to delete the row after the user has confirmed **AND** it has been successfully deleted from the database.

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')) {
    // shorter call for doing simple POST request
    $.post('delete.php', data, function (response) {
        // do something with response
    }, 'json');
    // ^ to indicate that the response will be of JSON format
}
```

But what `data` should be passed into the `$.post()` so that we know which record to delete? Well, probably the ID of the record that we want to delete.

**HTML**

As you have not posted much of the HTML, let's assume you built your table as below:

```
<table class="skuTable">
    <tr>
        <td>123</td><!-- sku group -->
        <td>456</td><!-- group id -->
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit" ... ></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more similar records -->
</table>
```

Change it so that you can easily find and access the ID of the group such as by adding a class to your cells. (Since we have already created an `onclick` handler, you no longer need to use `onclick` attribute for your `.delete` buttons.)

```
<table class="skuTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="skuGroup">123</td>
        <td class="groupId">456</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit" ... ></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more similar records -->
</table>
```

**JavaScript (again)**

You can easily find the associated ID by traversing using jQuery. To put everything together now:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    var button = $(this), 
        tr = button.closest('tr');
    // find the ID stored in the .groupId cell
    var id = tr.find('td.groupId').text();
    console.log('clicked button with id', id);

    // your PHP script expects GROUP_ID so we need to pass it one
    var data = { GROUP_ID: id };

    // ask confirmation
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')) {
        console.log('sending request');
        // delete record only once user has confirmed
        $.post('delete.php', data, function (res) {
            console.log('received response', res);
            // we want to delete the table row only we received a response back saying that it worked
            if (res.status) {
                console.log('deleting TR');
                tr.remove();
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

**PHP**

One of the reasons people use prepared statements is to prevent attacks. It's good that you tried to use it, but you are not using it right (read Jay's comment). 
You want to bind the variable to a parameter in your SQL. You can do this by passing an array of the variables in the [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) function.

When you delete a record, you check whether it worked by checking the number of records affected using [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

I've never had any reason to check whether `execute()` worked or not.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//$SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];

$Group_ID = $_POST['Group_ID'];

$host="xxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxx";

$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM SKU_Group_Dim WHERE Group_ID = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($Group_ID));

// send back the number of records it affected
$status = $stmt->rowCount() > 0;

// send back a JSON 
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));

// nothing else can be outputted after this
?>
```

Of course, this has not been tested so there may be few bugs. If you open up your browser's console log, you can follow the logs to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the code in my script and on run, nothing is happening when I click the delete button. Any idea why?

Comment: I edited the first 2 lines of the JS to look like this and the confirmation box is now displayed... `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener('click',function () {` However, it now tells me that the received response status is now false

Comment: Follow the code properly. Your HTML buttons should each have a `class` attribute **not** an `id` attribute. The buttons share this class because they share the same `onclick` event handler. IDs are only meant for one element, not several. Follow the console logs to ensure that you are getting the right values at each breakpoint. If the response status is false, look at what you are passing to the AJAX.

Comment: Okay, I have followed your code exactly, however nothing happens when I click the delete button so there is nothing to look at in the logs or anything

Comment: Ensure that you have (1) included jQuery (2) wrapped your jQuery code in [$(function() { ... });](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) (3) added `class="delete"` to your delete buttons (4) removed `onclick` attribute from your delete buttons.

Comment: I have included jQuery....I wrapped my code in `$(function() { ... });`...I added `class="delete"` and I removed the `onclick` attribute from my delete button. The confirmation now displays and in my logs I get `clicked button with id` after clicking the delete button and `sending request` once I hit "OK." However, that is all and nothing actually deletes

Comment: Better. The code is just the minimum to go about the problem. You will need to iron out/fix small details. Use your browser's tools to debug, particularly console and network/XHR tabs. Follow the logs and ask: are you getting the correct ID? Is AJAX firing? Are you passing the correct data? Are you getting back the correct JSON response? If one of these things don't work, find which log is wrong and try go back few steps. Also, check that you can connect to the database and run the expected SQL on its own. Maybe [turn on error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32064910/1022914).